# Howto make starter content in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I using JPA and MySQL in Spring boot. Howto make a initial content data of database?

Example, need create the basic sections, default admin user, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you take a look at Flyweight, It is nicely integrated into SpringBoot.

We use it to create the initial database, and for adding new tables or modifying the database when deploying new version of our application.

I would recommend that you create a script */resources/db/migration/V1__Initial.sql* Which just have the table layout and then a *V2__data.sql* with the initial data. 
A script can only be run once, and you can't modify it after it has been run, this information is stored in a table named schema_version, which you will probably have to delete, or manipulate during development. Here is a [link](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how)
to how it works - These days I would never do a real world project without using it.